# Bare metal RISC-V CPU - how does the processor know which address to start fetching instructions from?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, elf, riscv, riscv32

I am designing my own RISC-V CPU and have been able to implement a few instruction codes.

I have installed the RV32I version of the GCC compiler and so I now have the assembler `riscv32-unknown-elf-as` available.

I'm trying to assemble a program with just one instruction:

```
# simple.asm
add x5,x6,x7
```

I compile this with the assembler and then run objdump with this command:

```sh
riscv32-unknown-elf-as simple.asm -o simple
riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump -D simple
```

This prints out the following:

```
new:     file format elf32-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   007302b3                add     t0,t1,t2

Disassembly of section .riscv.attributes:

00000000 <.riscv.attributes>:
   0:   2d41                    jal     0x690
   2:   0000                    unimp
   4:   7200                    flw     fs0,32(a2)
   6:   7369                    lui     t1,0xffffa
   8:   01007663                bgeu    zero,a6,0x14
   c:   00000023                sb      zero,0(zero) # 0x0
  10:   7205                    lui     tp,0xfffe1
  12:   3376                    fld     ft6,376(sp)
  14:   6932                    flw     fs2,12(sp)
  16:   7032                    flw     ft0,44(sp)
  18:   5f30                    lw      a2,120(a4)
  1a:   326d                    jal     0xfffff9c4
  1c:   3070                    fld     fa2,224(s0)
  1e:   615f 7032 5f30          0x5f307032615f
  24:   3266                    fld     ft4,120(sp)
  26:   3070                    fld     fa2,224(s0)
  28:   645f 7032 0030          0x307032645f
```

My questions are:

1. What is going on here? I thought I'd have a simple single line of hex, but there's a lot more going on.
2. How do I instruct my processor to start reading the instructions at a certain memory address? It looks like objdump also doesn't know where the instructions will begin.

Just to be clear, I'm treating my processor as bare metal at this point. I am imagining I will hardcode in the processor that the instructions start at memory address X and data is available at memory address Y and stack is available at memory address Z. Is this correct? Or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: The actual CPU itself will have some hard-wired address that it fetches from on reset / power-on.  Usually a system will be designed with ROM or flash at that phys address.  (And might have code for an ELF program loader which will respect the ELF entry-point metadata, or you could just link a flat binary with the right code at the start of the binary.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - Thanks! Would it be possible to pass the file I compiled above as is to my processor? If yes, what changes do I need to make to have it get the instructions from the correct memory address?

Comment: `objdump -D` disassembles *all* ELF sections, not just `.text`.  As you can see, there is only one instruction in the `.text` section, and if you used `objdump -d` that's what you'd see.  (I normally use `objdump -drwC`, although `-w` is probably irrelevant for RISC-V)

Comment: *Would it be possible to pass the file I compiled above as is to my processor?* - Not in the way you're probably thinking.  Also note that you chose the wrong file name for the output.  `as` produces an object file (normally `.o`), not an executable.  You could link with `ld` into a flat binary, or `objcopy` the .text section out of it.  (You could in theory put the whole ELF executable or even object file into ROM such that the .text section happens to start where the CPU will fetch from, but nothing will look at the metadata bytes.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I see, I think I was looking at this wrong. I thought `as` generates the final binary, but from what you're saying I need to use `ld` to generate a file for my processor or use `objcopy` to copy the relevant bits to the correct addresses. Is that correct?

Comment: Close, but `objcopy` isn't fully an *alternative* to `ld`.  If you had code that used any labels for memory addresses, you'd need the linker to fill in those relocation entries in your code.  *Then* you could `objcopy` some sections out of a linked ELF executable. Or use a linker script to set the layout for your flat binary.  (For your simple case with only an `add`, no `la` or anything, there are no relocation entries so the text section in the .o is the same as in a linked executable.)  Also tricky to get right with `objcopy` is static data, e.g. `.data` and `.bss`...

Comment: @PeterCordes - Thank you, that makes perfect sense! Really appreciate your super fast help! If you could copy these comments into an answer I'm happy to accept, this is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: Your edits look more like an answer than part of a question.  If you want to post details of what worked for you, click the "answer my own question" box and post an actual answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Done! Sorry for the slow reply.

Comment: No worries, the whole point of Stack Overflow is for answers to be useful for years, so a few days is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@PeterCordes answer set me on the right path. I finally figured out how to generate a raw memory dump file that I can use.

The steps are as follows:

1. Modified the assembly file to have a `.text` and `.data` section and a `_start` label. My `simple.asm` file now looks as follows:

   ```
   .globl _start

   .text
   _start:
     add x5,x6,x7

   .data
   L1: .word 27
   ```
2. Assemble the `.asm` to a `.o` file using the following command:

   ```
   riscv32-unknown-elf-as simple.asm -o simple.o
   ```
3. Create a linker script for the specific processor. I followed this amazing [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7oKdUvRhQQ) which walks through the process on creating a linker script from scratch. For now, I just need `.text` and `.data` sections. So my linker script (`mycpu.ld`) is as shown below:

   ```
   OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littleriscv", "elf32-littleriscv", "elf32-littleriscv")
   ENTRY(_start)

   MEMORY
   {
     DATA (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x0, LENGTH = 0x80
     INST (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x80, LENGTH = 0x80
   }

   SECTIONS
   {
     .data :
     {
       *(.data)
     }> DATA

     .text :
     {
       *(.text)
     }> INST
   }
   ```
4. Generate the ELF file using `riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc` which automatically calls `riscv32-unknown-elf-ld`:

   ```
   riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -nostdlib -T mycpu.ld -o simple.elf simple.o
   ```
5. Create a raw binary or hex file from the `.elf` file which I will use to populate the contents of the memory.

   ```
   riscv32-unknown-elf-objcopy -O binary simple.elf simple.hex
   ```

Final `simple.hex` contains the following (using `hexyl`):

```
┌────────┬─────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┬────────┬────────┐
│00000000│ 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ┊ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │•0000000┊00000000│
│00000010│ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ┊ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │00000000┊00000000│
│00000020│ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ┊ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │00000000┊00000000│
│00000030│ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ┊ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │00000000┊00000000│
│00000040│ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ┊ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │00000000┊00000000│
│00000050│ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ┊ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │00000000┊00000000│
│00000060│ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ┊ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │00000000┊00000000│
│00000070│ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ┊ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │00000000┊00000000│
│00000080│ b3 02 73 00             ┊                         │×•s0    ┊        │
└────────┴─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

where `b3027300` is the hex value for `add x5,x6,x7`.

And that's it! Big thanks to @PeterCordes for his help! :)

Answer (score 5):

> how does the processor know which address to start fetching instructions from?

The actual CPU itself will have some hard-wired address that it fetches from on reset / power-on. Usually a system will be designed with ROM or flash at that phys address. (That ROM might have early-boot code for an ELF program loader which will respect the ELF entry-point metadata to set up an ELF kernel image from ROM, or you could just link a flat binary with the right code at the start of the binary.)

> What is going on here? I thought I'd have a simple single line of hex, but there's a lot more going on.

Your `objdump -D` disassembles all ELF sections, not just .text. As you can see, there is only one instruction in the .text section, and if you used objdump -d that's what you'd see. (I normally use `objdump -drwC`, although `-w` no line-wrapping is probably irrelevant for RISC-V, unlike x86 where a single insn can be long.)

> Would it be possible to pass the file I compiled above as is to my processor?

Not in the way you're probably thinking. Also note that you chose the wrong file name for the output. as produces an object file (normally .o), not an executable. You could link with `ld` into a flat binary, or link and `objcopy` the `.text` section out of it.

(You could in theory put a whole ELF executable or even object file into ROM such that the `.text` section happens to start where the CPU will fetch from, but nothing will look at the metadata bytes.  So the ELF entry-point address metadata in an ELF executable would be irrelevant.)

Difference between a `.o` and an executable: a `.o` just has relocation metadata for the linker to fill in actual addresses, absolute for `la` pseudo-instructions, or relative for [`auipc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574537/risc-v-pc-absolute-vs-pc-relative) in cases like multiple `.o` files where one references a symbol from the other.  (Otherwise the relative displacement could be calculated at assemble time, not left for link time.)

So if you had code that used any labels for memory addresses, you'd need the linker to fill in those relocation entries in your code. Then you could `objcopy` some sections out of a linked ELF executable. Or use a linker script to set the layout for your flat binary.

For your simple case with only an `add`, no `la` or anything, there are no relocation entries so the text section in the `.o` is the same as in a linked executable.

Also tricky to get right with `objcopy` is static data, e.g. `.data` and `.bss` sections.  If you copy *just* the `.text` section to a flat binary, you won't have data anywhere.  (But in a ROM, you'd need a startup function that copies static initializers from ROM to RAM for `.data`, and zeros the `.bss` space.  If you want to write the asm source to have a normal-looking `.data` section with non-zero values, you'd want your build scripts to figure out the size to copy so your startup function can use it, instead of having to manually do all that.)